# prism v5 service layer requesting User Input

Tags: prism

My authentication service layer (OAuth) in my Prism V5 WPF app, will handle creation of an Http client that is authenticated and ready to use for data calls. In some situations the service layer may receive a message from the server indicating that the user needs to resupply their login credentials in order to continue communicating with the server.
The service fires of a pubsub event saying "someone get me some crednetials from the user". And a UI component will recieve that message and interact with the user and somehow pass back the credentials to the service so it can carry on. I may have this architected a bit wrong.  what would be the best way for a service to handle the need for additional user input and carry on processing when it receives that input from the user. My service layer may make this call below.

```
    private UserCredentials AskUserForCredentials()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginCredentialsRequested>().Publish(new LoginCredentialsRequestedEventArgs());

       // wait for the input and return it here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interaction service, to do the work on your behalf. The user interaction including any required validation is then encapsulated in a separate service component. Your authentication service receives a reference to the interaction service through whatever dependency injection mechanism you are using and instead of publishing an event, the authentication service simply calls the appropriate  method on the interaction service to request the UserCredentials.

```
public interface IUserCredentialsInteractionService
{
    UserCredentials GetUserCredentials();
}

public class AuthenticationService
{
    IUserCredentialsInteractionService _interactionService;

    public AuthenticationService(IUserCredentialsInteractionService interactionService)
    {
        _interactionService = interactionService;
    }

    private UserCredentials AskUserForCredentials()
    {
        UserCredentials credentials = _interactionService.GetUserCredentials();
    }
}
```

The interaction service is just another component that you implement within the prism framework, however it may itself use a prism InteractionRequest object to communicate between its own view model and view.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a reasonable approach to call an agent in the UI via an interface, do whatever user interation is required and then return to the blocking caller once we have the info we need. Thanks, it makes total sense now, but I guess I was having a mental block last week. I'll try it out over the next couple of days and let you know the outcome.